# How to filter and render recurring nested JSON data in react native ListView?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, filter

I'm new to JSON and filtering. The **data.json** file and **FolderScreen.js** below render the following chapter structure in a `react native` `ListView`. With `react-navigation` props are passed down to render the related nested subchapters in the `ListView`.

This works flawlessly for `Chapter 1` and rendering it's `Subchapter A`, `B` and `C` in the `ListView`…

> Level 1 > **Chapter 1**
>
> > *Subchapter A*
> >
> > Subchapter B
> >
> > Subchapter C

… but as soon as `Subchapter A` is passed down to the **FolderScreen.js** all its `Sub-Subchapters A1`, `A2` and `A3` are not rendered as expected in the `ListView` with the snippet below…

> Level 2 > **Subchapter A**
>
> > Sub-Subchapter A1
> >
> > Sub-Subchapter A2
> >
> > Sub-Subchapter A3

**…am I missing something in the JSON filter?**

**Or just doing it wrong?**

---

## data.json

```js
{
   "id":"chapter-1",
   "name":"Chapter 1",
   "type":"folder",
   "content":[
  {
     "id":"sub-chapter-a",
     "name":"Subchapter A",
     "type":"folder",
     "content":[
        {
           "id":"sub-sub-chapter-a1",
           "name":"Sub-Subchapter A1",
           "type":"file"
        },
        {
           "id":"sub-sub-chapter-a2",
           "name":"Sub-Subchapter A2",
           "type":"file"
        },
        {
           "id":"sub-sub-chapter-a3",
           "name":"Sub-Subchapter A3",
           "type":"file"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"sub-chapter-b",
     "name":"Subchapter B",
     "type":"file"
  },
  {
     "id":"sub-chapter-c",
     "name":"Subchapter C",
     "type":"file"
  }
   ]
}
```

---

## FolderScreen.js

```js
renderRow = () => {

const entry = this.props.navigation.getParam('chapterID', '');

const listEntry = jsonData.map(all =>
    all.content.filter(parent => parent.id === entry).map(item =>
        item.content.map(i => {
            return (
                <ListEntry
                    id={i.id}
                    name={i.name}
                    type={i.type}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    key={i.id}
                />
            );
        })
    )
);

return listEntry;
};
```

---

## Big thanks for help!

Comment: Where is `jsonData` coming from? I suspect you could achieve this by passing each level's worth of data in via a prop, which would enable you to utilise recursive components very easily, by passing in the `.content` property to nested views.

Comment: it's a local JSON file imported in the **FolderScreen.js** via **import jsonData from '../content/data.json';**

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one. Your code expects there to always be a `content` property which is an array (or an object that has a `.map()` method, anyway).

In the innermost level, there is no `"content": []` property.

Either add one, or just add a check in for the `content` property before you try to use it.

My favorite technique is to use `(item.content || []).map(...`, to use an empty array if the property is null or undefined.

Comment: Cheers for the lightning-fast reply – I changed the following lines, but it still doesn't do the trick: **(all.content || all).filter(parent…** and **(item.content || [ ]).map(i => { … }** Thx for a quick snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Your last map returns an array with only one entry. You need to access the first array item [0] or modify your code to iterate through results.

Here is a simplified version of what works:

```
const listEntry = jsonData.content
  .filter(sub => sub.id === entry)
  .map(subsub => subsub.content)[0]
  .map(item => { 
      return <ListEntry id={item.id} name={item.name}/> 
  }
);
```

So you should change your code to access the first array member before using the last .map:

```
const listEntry = jsonData.map(all =>
  all.content.filter(parent => parent.id === entry).map(item =>
    item.content)[0].map(i => {
        return (
            <ListEntry
                id={i.id}
                name={i.name}
                type={i.type}
                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                key={i.id}
            />
        );
    })
)
);
```

Here is a working Snack for my sample code: https://snack.expo.io/@navardan/nested-contents

Here is also a good article on .map and .filter [Simplify your JavaScript – Use .map(), .reduce(), and .filter()](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d)